# pgfplots, overshooting problem

Tags: pgfplots

How can I avoid the overshooting below 0?

[image: graph]

This is the code I use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}


\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={solid},
    every tick/.append style={semithick,color=black}, 
}


\begin{axis}[smooth,

scale only axis = true, width = 0.9\textwidth , height = 0.35\textwidth,
scaled ticks = false,
minor tick num =0,
thick,
ymin =-0.2, ymax =0.7, xmin =0,  xmax=72, 

legend style={font=\footnotesize, 
    legend pos =north west},

tickwidth = 0.15cm,
grid style ={dashed},

ylabel = {y}, 
xlabel={x},
grid = both
]


\addplot [no markers] coordinates{
(0,0.5)
(2,0.0)
(4,0.01)
(6,0.02)
(8,0.03)
(10,0.06)
(12,0.09)
(14,0.13)
(16,0.18)
(18,0.23)
(20,0.28)
(22,0.32)
(24,0.36)
(26,0.40)
(28,0.43)
(30,0.46)
(32,0.48)
(34,0.50)
(36,0.51)
(38,0.53)
(40,0.54)



} ;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "overshooting"?

Comment: When you look at the y-values, they don't go below zero

Comment: Don't use `smooth`.

Comment: Two unrelated things: `\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}` isn't needed when you already have `\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}`. And empty lines inside the optional argument to `axis` isn't allowed, it will cause errors. (Which is why Mike added the `%` in his answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options here:

- don't use `smooth`, which makes hard corners (not shown below),
- set `tension` to a lower value, which reduces the overshot, but makes harder corners,
- if permissible, you could add a point, or
- you could combine the last two options (not shown below)

(The legend shows the value for `tension`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}


\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={solid},
    every tick/.append style={semithick,color=black}, 
}


\begin{axis}[smooth,
%
scale only axis = true, width = 0.9\textwidth , height = 0.35\textwidth,
scaled ticks = false,
minor tick num =0,
thick,
ymin =-0.2, ymax =0.7, xmin =0,  xmax=72, 
%
legend style={font=\footnotesize, 
    legend pos =north west},
%
tickwidth = 0.15cm,
grid style ={dashed},
%
ylabel = {y}, 
xlabel={x},
grid = both
]


\addplot+[no markers,tension=0.2] coordinates{
(0,0.5)
(2,0.0)
(4,0.01)
(6,0.02)
(8,0.03)
(10,0.06)
(12,0.09)
(14,0.13)
(16,0.18)
(18,0.23)
(20,0.28)
(22,0.32)
(24,0.36)
(26,0.40)
(28,0.43)
(30,0.46)
(32,0.48)
(34,0.50)
(36,0.51)
(38,0.53)
(40,0.54)
} ;
\addlegendentry{0.2}

% default value: tension=0.55
\addplot+[no markers] coordinates{
(0,0.5)
(2,0.0)
(4,0.01)
(6,0.02)
(8,0.03)
(10,0.06)
(12,0.09)
(14,0.13)
(16,0.18)
(18,0.23)
(20,0.28)
(22,0.32)
(24,0.36)
(26,0.40)
(28,0.43)
(30,0.46)
(32,0.48)
(34,0.50)
(36,0.51)
(38,0.53)
(40,0.54)
} ;
\addlegendentry{0.55 (default)}

\addplot+[no markers,tension=0.9] coordinates{
(0,0.5)
(2,0.0)
(4,0.01)
(6,0.02)
(8,0.03)
(10,0.06)
(12,0.09)
(14,0.13)
(16,0.18)
(18,0.23)
(20,0.28)
(22,0.32)
(24,0.36)
(26,0.40)
(28,0.43)
(30,0.46)
(32,0.48)
(34,0.50)
(36,0.51)
(38,0.53)
(40,0.54)
} ;
\addlegendentry{0.9}

\addplot+[no markers] coordinates{
(0,0.5)
(1,0.1) % added point
(2,0.0)
(4,0.01)
(6,0.02)
(8,0.03)
(10,0.06)
(12,0.09)
(14,0.13)
(16,0.18)
(18,0.23)
(20,0.28)
(22,0.32)
(24,0.36)
(26,0.40)
(28,0.43)
(30,0.46)
(32,0.48)
(34,0.50)
(36,0.51)
(38,0.53)
(40,0.54)
} ;
\addlegendentry{added point}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Not using smooth in combination with tension, works perfectly!

Comment: If you don't use `smooth`, `tension` has no effect.