# PGFPlots renders spotty curves - not smooth

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following code, which renders the graph as "spotty" (for a lack of a better word):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            title=Hyperbolsk funktion,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            xmin=-5,    xmax=5,
            ymin=-5,    ymax=5,
            xtick={-1,0,1},
            ytick={-1,0,1},
            axis line style={->},
            ymajorgrids=true,
            xmajorgrids=true,
            grid style=dashed,
            grid style=thin,
            grid style=black,
            legend pos=south east
        ]
            \addplot[color=blue,domain=-5:5,smooth]{sinh(x)};
            \addlegendentry{f(x)=sinh(x)}
            \addplot[color=red,domain=-5:5]{cosh(x)};
            \addlegendentry{f(x)=cosh(x)}
            \addplot[color=green,domain=-5:5]{tanh(x)};
            \addlegendentry{f(x)=tanh(x)}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I would like this code to output a smooth curve, yet it outputs the following:
[image]

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Increasing the number of samples will work, but adding the `smooth` keyword to the two last plots will also work (you only have it on the first). In general, be a bit careful with `smooth` (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400967/ and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371245), but in this case it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add 'samples=xxx' to your \addplot lines inside the square brackets. This allows you to choose how many samples you want it to take, with more samples having smoother curves with a trade off of slower compiling speeds. 100 should be fine for most curves. Without adding this, it uses the default amount of samples, which gives less 'curvy' curves.

An easier way of doing this if you wish *all* your amount of samples to be the same is to add `\pgfplotsset{samples=xxx}` to the preamble, which sets the default to 'xxx'.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            title=Hyperbolsk funktion,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            xmin=-5,    xmax=5,
            ymin=-5,    ymax=5,
            xtick={-1,0,1},
            ytick={-1,0,1},
            axis line style={->},
            ymajorgrids=true,
            xmajorgrids=true,
            grid style=dashed,
            grid style=thin,
            grid style=black,
            legend pos=south east
        ]
            \addplot[color=blue,domain=-5:5,smooth, samples=100]{sinh(x)};//Note the change here
            \addlegendentry{f(x)=sinh(x)}
            \addplot[color=red,domain=-5:5, samples=100]{cosh(x)}; //Note the change
            \addlegendentry{f(x)=cosh(x)}
            \addplot[color=green,domain=-5:5, samples=100]{tanh(x)}; //Note the change
            \addlegendentry{f(x)=tanh(x)}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```